# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY] while running Tango project in android studio

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I just downloaded a sample project (tango) from this [link](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/java/) and imported it to android studio and started running the project. But when I run the project in my android phone, it gives an error

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]

I dont know what the issue is with it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The "missing shared library" is a the tango library that exists only on Tango enabled devices.

You should use the Tango Tablet Development Kit or other Tango enabled device run Tango sample.

Answer (score -1):

The problem comes up because for external jars its not required to declare library on manifest... Deleting on manifest the writed on the post solves the problem

Comment: i removed declared libraries and tried to run the app.app started and crashed with error                   No implementation found for int com.google.atap.tango.TangoJNINative.Initialize(android.content.Context) (tried Java_com_google_atap_tango_TangoJNINative_Initialize and Java_com_google_atap_tango_TangoJNINative_Initialize__Landroid_content_Context_2)